# Bind unequal list of dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have list of dataframes like this:

```
 listdata <- list(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3),nrow=2,ncol=4),matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),ncol=1),matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),nrow=2))
 FrameData <- lapply(listdata, function(x) as.data.frame(x))
```

How I would rbind the list od dataframes so that I would exclude the 1 column vector?
The final output I would like is:

```
    V1 V2 V3 V4
1   1  1  3  3
2   1  1  3  3
3   1  1  2  2
4   1  1  2  2
```

Comment: `rbind.fill` from package `plyr` is also an option vs. `do.call`; `rbind.fill(Filter(function(x) ncol(x)>1, FrameData))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by subsetting your list and using a `do.call`

```
do.call(rbind, FrameData[sapply(FrameData, function(x) ncol(x)>1)])
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1  1  3  3
# 2  1  1  3  3
# 3  1  1  2  2
# 4  1  1  2  2
```

Here i just check that each data.frame has more than one column

Comment: Yeah, this was my first approach with `ncol(x)>1` but obviously could make it work..!Thanks.

Comment: +1. Could also use Filter. `do.call(rbind, Filter(function(x) ncol(x)>1, FrameData))`

Comment: Great!I know about function `Filter()` but I was unsure how to apply!Thanks.